# Hive Sort When Running GroupBy

Tags: sql, hive

I have a Hive table with data like below:
HIVE table

"partition, id, seq, raw"

```
xm1, aaa, 3, <end>
xm1, aaa, 2, <middle>
xm1, aab, 1, <begin>
xm1, aaa, 1, <begin>
xm1, aab, 3, <end>
xm1, aab, 2, <middle>
```

What I would like to do is run a Select SQL that will return the "partition, id, and []" based on seq

I am getting back the collected set in a different order "xm1, aaa, []."

How can I use the Sequence number to get this information back in order? I can't use sequence in the group by.

I am running a SQL statement like below:

```
SELECT partition, id, collect_set(raw) 
FROM test_rpt_sorted 
WHERE id='aaa' 
GROUP BY partition, id
```

Comment: returned data from the SQL should be partition, id, [<begin><middle><end>], data returned is sending the collected_set in random order [<middle><begin><end>]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `sort_array` built-in function to enforce an ordering upon the result of `collect_set`.

```
SELECT partition, id, sort_array(collect_set(seq))
FROM test_rpt_sorted
WHERE id='aaa'
GROUP BY partition, id;
```

Do note that per [HIVE-2279](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2279), the `sort_array` function is available as of Hive 0.9.0 (hopefully your installation is not older than that).

Comment: I had a copy error in my original SQL. the Collect_set was collecting the raw field.